# Creating a slice of slice of interfaces in go

Tags: go, slice, literals, variable-declaration

I'm trying to create a function that returns the all the `key, value` of a `map` as a `slice` of `slice` of tuples (where each tuple is `{key, value}`)

Here's the code:

```
func ReturnTuples(map_ map[interface{}]interface{}) [][]interface{} {
    toReturn := []([]interface{})
    ...
```

But I'm getting error for the `toReturn` line:

```
type [][]interface {} is not an expression
```

How should I declare a slice of slice of interfaces? I see this as the only way. I tried without parenthesis like:

```
[][]interface{}
```

but it won't work either.

I tried to search for 'golang slice of slice' on google but very few things appear. For example I've only found how to create a simple one made of `uint8`, which is: `[][]uint8`.

Comment: Why the negative vote? How should I know it? I tried []([]interface{}){} which was the most intuitive but didn't work. I've found nothing in google too.

Comment: I'm not the one who downvoted, but did you really try `[]([]interface{}){}`? Because that works... [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/z8XInz95Gg)

Comment: @icza yes, I tried, but I don't remember if the error was exactly the same as mine now, but thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The element type of the slice is `interface{}`, so a [composite literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals) needs an additional pair of braces: `[]interface{}{}`.

In case of slice of slices:

```
toReturn := [][]interface{}{}
```

Or when using `make()`, you specify a *type* (and not a composite literal):

```
toReturn := make([][]interface{}, 0, len(map_))
```

Comment: Just adding to this, you can also do `var toReturn [][]interface{}` if you don't want to bother with initialization.

Answer (score 2):

You're creating an instance, not defining a type, so you need an extra pair of curly braces to initialize the variable:

```
toReturn := [][]interface{}{}
```